# What is the best way for me to find what CMS a webpage is using?

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I am taking over this project. The previous developer left absolutely no documentation as to what was done.

I normally log onto 'built with' to find out what technologies were used, but that is not giving me much info.

At this point I am thinking it is on Magento or something, but I can not be 100% sure.

Comment: Inspecting the source is usually helpful. If you don't see anything prefixed with `wp`, it's likely not WordPress.

Comment: @rnevius Yeah, I am sure its not wordpress. I usually test that by inspecting and then adding 'wp-admin.php' to the end of the URL. Is there anyway to find out what it is though?

Comment: Can you please provide us your project URL?? So, we can tell you what cms it is using.

Comment: The URL is http://youngandng.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use a browser addon such as:
Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10229/

Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae

If you want to do it manually:

For WordPress - CTRL + F -> Search for "/wp-content/"

For Drupal - CTRL + F -> Search for "/sites/"  (I think you may also be able to simply search "Drupal")

For Magento - CTRL + F -> Search for "/skin/frontend/"

Comment: Great Plugin! Only problem is the webpage I am using this tool for displays no CMS. Only the jQuery, and when I check manually I get no WP, no Magento, or Drupal using the search queries you mentioned.

Comment: Do you want to link me to the webpage and I can do some digging? Then I can let you know how I found it :)

Comment: Hi, this seems to have been built with Bootstrap and is not using a "CMS" as such?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your continuous help, I was able to find out it was in fact on Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these online detection sites:

http://w3techs.com/sites/

http://builtwith.com/